# Loading data into an object derived from base classes php

Tags: php, interface, abstract-class

I have started writing a library of e-commerce classes in PHP as abstract classes with the intention of forcing the implementation of concrete classes to use a load() method which loads data into the objects:

```php
abstract Cart {
    abstract function load();
    // other stuff ...
}

class MyCart extends Cart {
    public function load()
    {
        // pull in data from anywhere ...
    }
}
```

I was wondering if this is the right way to go about doing this...

I want to:

- Keep the core library un-touched.
- Keep it very simple, we intend to re-use this code and other people will be implementing it.

I've heard about adapters and things, although I haven't looked into these (yet).. can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers,
John.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an abstract class, I would recommend using interfaces for this purpose:

```
interface Cart {
  public function load();
  // other stuff ...
}

class MyCart implements Cart {
  public function load()
  {
    // pull in data from anywhere ...
  }
}
```

Interfaces are used to describe the structure of a deriving class, it's the best way if you want to add different classes all offering the same methods. Another advantage would be that a class can only extend one parent class (i.e. your Cart class) but can implement several interfaces.
Read more about [interfaces on PHP.net](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php), here's one excerpt underlining why I think this pattern would fit your requirement:

> Object interfaces allow you to create code which specifies which methods a class must implement, without having to define how these methods are handled.

Comment: I actually used interfaces and abstract classes as I wanted to enforce the method to be created later on and also wanted to provide a bit of functionality.

Comment: So why did you switch to abstract classes instead? The only advantage I could think of is to provide some non-abstract functions with programming logic in the parent class and class-dependant implementations of (abstract) functions in the child classes.